# What is a shorter way to rewrite this using Pandas?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have these functions calculating the value of time strings in seconds.

What is a shorter way to achieve this using built-in `pandas` methods?

```py
import re
import math

data = pd.DataFrame(["54 minutes 45 seconds","3 hours 12 minutes","2 hours 7 minutes","15 minutes 12 seconds","51 minutes 35 seconds"], columns = ["Matching"])

def get_match(string,pattern):
    if not string != string:
        found = pattern.search(string)
        if found != None:
            value = re.compile("\d{1,}").search(found[0])
            return int(value[0])
    return 0 

def convert_time(col):

    for index, row in col.iteritems():
        min_p = re.compile("\d{1,}\sminutes")
        sec_p = re.compile("\d{1,}\sseconds")    
        hr_p = re.compile("\d{1,}\shours")    
        mins = get_match(row, min_p)
        secs = get_match(row, sec_p)
        hrs = get_match(row, hr_p)
        time = mins * 60 + secs + hrs * 60 * 60
        col[index] = time


convert_time(data["Matching"])
data.head()
```

Comment: I believe instead of multiple regex you can achieve your result using 1 regex only.

Comment: Thank you @Mandy8055 can you provide an example?

Comment: kindly post your expected output. makes it easier for whoever answers to ensure their result matches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest a simple helper function that extracts the three time components at once and
maps its values to their equivalent in seconds using a dictionary:

```
in_seconds = {'hours': 60 * 60, 'minutes': 60, 'seconds': 1}
sec = sum(int(num) * in_seconds[eq] for num, eq in re.findall(r'(\d+)\s?(hours|minutes|seconds)', "54 minutes 45 seconds"))
```

### Wrapped in a function and using [pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```py
import re

def sec(x):
    in_seconds = {'hours': 60 * 60, 'minutes': 60, 'seconds': 1}
    return sum(int(num) * in_seconds[eq] for num, eq in re.findall(r'(\d+)\s?(hours|minutes|seconds)', x))


df.Matching = df.Matching.apply(sec)
```

### Using [pandas.Series.str.findall](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html)

```py
in_seconds = {'hours': 60 * 60, 'minutes': 60, 'seconds': 1}

df.Matching = df.Matching.str.findall('(\d+)\s?(hours|minutes|seconds)').apply(lambda x: sum(int(num) * in_seconds[eq] for num, eq in x))
```

Comment: You did the hard part